# Java InvocationTargetException & NoSuchMethodError for hbase shaded client (or commons)

Tags: java, maven, hadoop, hbase

I'm getting a bunch of errors regarding HBase connection, but it's related to a missing string library or something wrong with my pom.xml.

I cut a lot of errors out but:

> java.io.IOException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:240) ~[hbase-shaded-client-1.2.3.jar!/:1.2.3]

.. further down

```
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_72-internal]
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_72-internal]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_72-internal]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_72-internal]
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_72-internal]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:238) ~[hbase-shaded-client-1.2.3.jar!/:1.2.3]
        ... 98 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.util.StringUtils.toLowerCase(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.HdfsServerConstants$RollingUpgradeStartupOption.getAllOptionString(HdfsServerConstants.java:80) ~[hadoop-hdfs-2.7.3.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<clinit>(NameNode.java:264) ~[hadoop-hdfs-2.7.3.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.NameNodeProxies.createProxy(NameNodeProxies.java:176) ~[hadoop-hdfs-2.7.3.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:678) ~[hadoop-hdfs-2.7.3.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:619) ~[hadoop-hdfs-2.7.3.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.initialize(DistributedFileSystem.java:149) ~[hadoop-hdfs-2.7.3.jar!/:na]
```

..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example.sp</groupId>
    <artifactId>sp-bootapp</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>My great SpringBootApp</name>
    <description>Jst a really cool app</description>    

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
                <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                <version>9.4-1200-jdbc4</version>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
            <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.2</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
            <artifactId>transport</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions> 
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>21.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.2</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
            <version>4.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-csv</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
            <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
            <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.2</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.3</version>
            <exclusions>  
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
                    <artifactId>netty-all</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
            <artifactId>hbase-shaded-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.4</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.3</version>
        </dependency>               
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
            <artifactId>tika-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
            <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jmockit</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmockit</artifactId>
            <version>1.20</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>


</project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it, but I think it was Guava 16.0 that was required by something, and Guava 21.0 had deprecated util.toLowerCase or something.